# vb.net draw brush picturebox location uncorrect place of mouse cursor

Tags: vb.net

I draw brush in picturebox  but the location of the drawing appears away from the place of mouse cursor
and it always appear on top of the picture
Note This happen when sizemode in picture is set to StretchImage

```
  Sub drawBrush(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(PictureBox1.Image)
        Dim x, y As Integer
        x = e.Location.X
        y = e.Location.Y
        Label1.Text = x.ToString
        Label2.Text = y.ToString
        Width = 2
        If x = 0 Then
            x = y
        End If
        Dim brush As SolidBrush = New SolidBrush(color)
        Dim pen1 As Pen = New Pen(color, 4)
        g.DrawRectangle(pen1, e.X, e.Y, 10, 10)
        g.FillRectangle(brush, e.X, e.Y, 10, 10)
    End Using
    PictureBox1.Invalidate()
End Sub
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    If draw Then
        drawBrush(e)
    End If
   end Sub
```

Comment: Does the `Image` perfectly fill the `PictureBox`? If not then the location of the mouse pointer relative to the `Image` is not the same as the location relative to the `PictureBox`. You are using the latter but using it as though it is the former.

Comment: picture  sizemode is set to StretchImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use the stretched image after being stretched
using    PictureBox1.CreateGraphics.DrawRectangle

```
  Private draw As Boolean = False
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
    draw = True
End Sub
Sub drawBrush(ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs)
    Label1.Text = CStr(e.X)
    Label2.Text = CStr(e.Y)
    PictureBox1.CreateGraphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Beige, e.X, e.Y, 10, 10)
End Sub
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    If draw Then
        drawBrush(e)
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseUp(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseUp
    draw = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage`, that only affects what you see on the screen. The `Image` object doesn't change. Let's say that you have an `Image` that is 10x10 and a `PictureBox` that is 100x100. If you put the mouse pointer in the centre of the control then the location will be (50, 50). If the `Image` is only 10x10, how could (50, 50) possibly be used for a point in the `Image`? You would need to do some arithmetic to scale your mouse coordinates based on the scaling of the `Image`. If the `Image` is stretched by N times in a direction then you have to divide the mouse coordinate by N in that direction to map to the corresponding point on the actual `Image`:

```vb
finalValue = imageDimension * initialValue / controlDimension
```

That's going to give you a `Double` value, so you need to decide what you want to do with that. You might convert it to a `Single` and then use the overloads of `DrawRectangle` and `FillRectangle` that accept `Single` values.

Comment: the stretch is automatic, how to calculate the scales

Comment: can you provide sample for value x and y

Comment: @mazenmougi, calculating the scaling is arithmetic, not programming, so it shouldn't even need to be demonstrated. Never the less, I have demonstrated it. You don't need to ask for something that is already in the answer provided.

Comment: If it is arithmetic how to apply it to the given example.